# How FaceBook is managing and removing the margins in landscape and keyboard open mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I wonder and not getting how facebook manages to fit the layout on all screen sizes by removing the padding or margins as shown below in landscape mode and open keyboard mode.

If anyone has implemented the same or getting the logic behind it please let me know.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you place the elements inside a `ScrollView`, they will automatically move up when the keyboard is open. You must also have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for the appropriate `Activity`.

Comment: thanks I have my layout in scrollview but not manifest attribute. I will try this and will update here . Also let me know do I also need to have configchnages= "orientation|keyboardhidden"

Comment: I have extracted Manifest from facebook apk but they don't have such in there LoginActivity inside manifest.

Comment: `orientation|keyboardhidden` means that you will handle orientation changes yourself in an `onConfigurationChanged` function overridden in the `Activity`. Check here for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html